# Screenshot software not taking screenshots while not connected (RDP)

Tags: windows, screenshot, rdp

I've a little Windows Server (Windows Web Server 2008) on which I need to monitor the desktop. I've placed a little application on it which takes screenshots now and then and uploads them to a FTP - but as soon as I disconnect (not logout) via RDP the Screenshot is not refreshed (but uploaded). Is there any setting I have to change so the RDP session will keep taking up to date screens?

Comment: If no user is logged-in then there's no desktop left to take a screenshot of.  This can only continue to run and upload blackness when your error checking is inadequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you`ve disconnected users session automatically logsout. So may be you should run app on the under loged in user account. And also may be screen "freezes" and do not updating, so when you capturing it there is the same screen as before

Comment: Usually there is no user logged in on this machine - so I'm using RDP only. There has to be a possibility to prevent session logout as I am disconnecting with the close of RDP not trough the logout button.

Comment: I think I just got it working - it really did log me out while closing the RDP client. Alternatively I was able to disconnect via 'tscon.exe rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console' - and the desktop keeps refreshing! Thanks!